# Access Denied when join with table User using JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to join the `Permissions` table with `Users` table via `createdBy` field. But I get the error below, I don't understand what the problem is, am I doing something wrong? And is there a better way for me to join the `Permissions` table with the `Users` table to get user information?

My error:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:520) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:305) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

User Entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity(name = "users")
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    public User() {}

    public User(String title, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, String email, String password, LocalDate dob, String gender, String avatarUrl, Long roleId, Boolean status, String countryCode, String phoneNumber, String authenticationCode, LocalDateTime sendAuthenticationCodeAt, Long createdBy) {
        this.title = title;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
        this.status = status;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.authenticationCode = authenticationCode;
        this.sendAuthenticationCodeAt = sendAuthenticationCodeAt;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String middleName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    private LocalDate dob;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 5)
    private String gender;

    private String avatarUrl;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private Boolean status;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(length = 15)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(length = 6)
    private String authenticationCode;

    private LocalDateTime sendAuthenticationCodeAt;

    private int numberLoginFailed;

    private String forgotPasswordToken;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long createdBy;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    private Long deletedBy;

    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return status;
    }

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Permission permission;
}
```

Permission entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity(name = "permissions")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Permission {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String slug;

    private Long createdBy;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "createdBy", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

If I quit connecting the 2 boards, the error message goes away and everything works normally.

Comment: Why the use of `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` ?

Comment: Did you tried to use public on the user field in Permission entity?

Comment: @PeterMmm I removed it but it still not working

Comment: @stylepatrick, t tired it, but it sitll not working

Comment: `org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter` makes part of the security framework of Spring. The exception tells that the request has not the required authorities. You should show the relevant code of security setup of your Spring app.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMmm, i resloved my problem by adding     ```@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)```. I'm not sure why this makes it work.